# Sort MongoDB collection based on value of a field of an embedded object specified by a field value?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In MongoDB, how would I go about sorting a query result based on the value of a field of an embedded object that is specified by another field value?

Here's a representation of the data:

```
{
field1 : 'value',
field2: 'value',
data: [
    fields": [
    {
    _id: "5a8fdd13de5b074d4d4f572c",
    field: "location",
    value: "Antwerp"
    },
    {
    _id: "5a8fdd13de5b074d4d4f572b",
    field: "title",
    value: "This is a good title"
    },
    {
    _id: "5a8fdd13de5b074d4d4f572a",
    field: "employmentType",
    value: "Temporary"
    }
]}
```

So for example, I have a collection with documents like this one and I'd like to sort the whole collection based on `data.fields.value`. And the only thing I have is `data.fields.field`.

How would I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, have you already tried accomplishing this yourself? This site rather helps resolving errors than writing code for you

Comment: Yeah, I have, but I eventually figured out I need to sort the parent documents using a value in the nested documents. And I haven't found how to do this yet...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by you have `field`. Is `field` a user input ? How is `field` related to `value` ?

Comment: Oh yeah, wasn't to clear. I fixed it now! I meant `data.fields.field` and `data.fields.value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in 3.4.

The idea is to project the field where it matches the field. `location` in below query.

[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to keep the computed document as the extra field in the document followed by [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) sort on value field in the document.

[`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)  to transform field object inside fields to array of key value pairs inside [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) with [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/) with [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) to match the key (field) and value(location).

[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#exclude-fields-from-output-documents) with exclusion to drop the sort document to get document with original fields.

[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to transform the array with single document to single document.

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {"$addFields":{
    "mfield":{
      "$arrayElemAt":{
        "$filter":{
          "input":{"$arrayElemAt":["$data.fields",0]},
          "as":"field",
          "cond":{
            "$let":{
              "vars":{"fieldkv":{"$objectToArray":"$$field"}},
              "in":{
                "$and":[
                  {"$in":["field", "$$fieldkv.k"]},
                  {"$in":["location", "$$fieldkv.v"]}
                ]
              }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$sort":{"mfield.value":-1}},
  {"$project":{"mfield":0}}
])
```

Comment: Looks good! To get the index of the field I want to sort by, could I use (in a previous aggregation) $indexOfArray?

Comment: Yes you can. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: You specify in your example that you want to sort by the object with `field: 'location'`. Because of that you use index of 0 in `$arrayElemAt`. The field I want to sort by isn't set, so it has to be dynamic. Getting the index using `$indexOfArray` would make this dynamic, no?

Comment: `$arrayElemAt` with 0 index to output the first element in `data` array which is `fields`. Is that not the case ?

Comment: I get that. But you used `$data.fields` in $arrayElemAt, wouldn't that give me the first element in `fields`?

Comment: `{$arrayElemAt:["$data", 0]}` will output `{fields:[values]}` whereas `$data.fields` will be something `[[values]]`. So when you use `$arrayElemAt` with 0 index,  it is `[values]`

Comment: Oh right, gotcha, misunderstood some stuff then. I got it working but I removed the first `$arrayElemAt`, because it was giving me issues and in my case it doesn't really need to be there. There'll always be only one object with a specific field name.

Btw, the `$arrayElemAt` was complaining about there only being one argument, since no index was giving.

Comment: No need to use `$arrayElemAt ` then. Just use `"input":"$data.fields"` if data is a just a document.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
    {$sort : {"data.fields.value" : 1}}
])
```

will sort the results in ascending order.

You can replace the `1` with `-1` if you would like to sort the collection in descending order instead.

Comment: Isn't this the same as `db.collection_name.find().sort({"data.fields.value" : 1})`? I want to sort on a specific `data.fields.value`, which one is specified by the value of `data.fields.field`. I haven't found a way to do this yet...

Answer (score 0):

You have nested sub documents .In order to sort the nested sub document unwind to that particular document.

```
db.collection_name.aggregate(
     {$unwind: "$data"},
     {$unwind: "$data.fields"},
{$sort : {"data.fields.value" : -1}},
{$group: {_id:"$_id", fields: {$push:"$data.fields"}}})
```

Comment: Learned somethin new, didn't know `unwind`. That's not exactly what I'm looking for... I want to sort the parent documents based on the field of the nested document. And I specify which nested document using the `data.fields.field` field